# Get column name based on row name

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

[image]

I want to fetch row V1 whoes value is 1 and get column name according to that value
for eg `v1 = d1,d2,d5,d6,d8,d9` in mysql

I forgot to mention that my column is added dynamically.

**Edited: - Question Explanation...**

OPs want to select column name where variant_id = "v1" and where d1 - d9 column have 1 value...

Comment: Please read [mcve] and post your attemps

Comment: Rows dont have names,

Comment: `SELECT d1,d2,d5,d6,d8,d9 FROM online_defect_table_2 WHERE variant_id = 'V1';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you know how to fetch results from a database, and I'm going to assume you have all values of V1 stored in a variable called `$row`.

You could loop through the row and get all keys where the value is not 0.

```
$confirmedColumns = [];
foreach($row as $column => $value){
    if($value == 1) {
        // []= means "append to array", similar to how += appends to strings
        $confirmedColumns[]= $column;
    }
}

print_r($confirmedColumns);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using concat and if

```
    select  concat( 
          if(d1, 'd1', null) 
        , if(d2, ',d2', null) 
        , if(d3, ',d3', null) 
        , if(d4, ',d4', null) 
        , if(d5, ',d5', null)
        , if(d6, ',d6', null)
        , if(d7, ',d7', null)
        , if(d8, ',d8', null) 
        , if(d9, ',d9', null)
        )
    from online_defect_table
    where variant_id = 'V1'
```

or for avoid problem if all the operands are null

```
    select  concat( 
          if(d1, 'd1', '') 
        , if(d2, ',d2', '') 
        , if(d3, ',d3', '') 
        , if(d4, ',d4', '') 
        , if(d5, ',d5', '')
        , if(d6, ',d6', '')
        , if(d7, ',d7', '')
        , if(d8, ',d8', '') 
        , if(d9, ',d9', '')
        )
    from online_defect_table
    where variant_id = 'V1'
```

Comment: `variant_id = 'V1'` ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly   thanks  ...  answer updated ..

Comment: `CONCAT` will return NULL if **any** operand is NULL.

Comment: correct answer  updated also for operand null